For microphone based live transcription, using StreamingRecognizeRequest works till 305 seconds
We are using google speech to text “StreamingRecognizeRequest” for microphone based live transcription. The problem we are facing is that after 5min we are getting below error.
Error: Exceeded maximum allowed stream duration of 305 seconds.
Some of the link we got for long duration was for file based implementation, but these are not synchronous transcription.
Links -  https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize
Could you please help us, how we can achieve long duration parallel synchronous transcription. We have integrated google API in our product for live transcription, but after every 5min it fails, we need to recreate the stream.

On this page of the google docs you can see the limit you are talking about of 5 minutes
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas?hl=en
There is also a page with examples to achieve what you are looking for here:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-streaming-audio?hl=en#endless-streaming
and then there is this github repository here with a java example on how to do that:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/main/speech/src/main/java/com/example/speech/InfiniteStreamRecognize.java
Have you tried running their example to process longer streams?
